# Why does the ubuntu password screen take longer on a wrong password?

Tags: 11.04, password, login-screen

I noticed that a check on a good password takes ~.5 seconds. However, if you give a password that is incorrect, it takes ~3 seconds to inform the user as such. Why is this?

Comment: This is probably a safeguard to limit the rate at which passwords can be guessed. Hopefully an answer can be posted confirming (or debunking) this. (Then this comment can be removed as obsolete.)

Comment: This is indeed for security. @EliahKagan ,Your comment is good enough as an answer for this question. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there a delay when entering a wrong password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474080/why-is-there-a-delay-when-entering-a-wrong-password)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its for the security of the operating system. The arbitrary wait is to check brute-force attacks.

Duplicate Question: https://serverfault.com/questions/16232/ubuntu-linux-takes-longer-time-for-incorrect-passwords